Is there a way to access Cookies in Blazor with @rendermode="InteractiveAuto" in the Oninitialized hook
I know how to access cookies in Blazor in the OnAfterRender hook using Javascript. But, I need to access cookies in Oninitialized before javascript is available.
I've tried the adding the following:
[CascadingParameter]
    private HttpContext HttpContext { get; set; }

but the IDE complains that it doesn't even know what HttpContext is.
Can anyone please help me access cookies from Oninitialized?

The reason the IDE complains is it's not possible.

:( I could do it when I used Nuxt. I just prefer to work with C# than Javascript. Oh well. Thank you though.

The "Auto" render actually will experience 3 mode:

SSR(server static prerender): HttpContext available.  JSInterop not work.
ServerInterActive: HttpContext not available. JSInterop work.
WASMInterActive:  HttpContext not available. JSInterop work.

So you need to operate cookie depending on the mode. First install Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http 2.2.2 in "client project". (it's said deprecated, but still can be used.). Then you can operate cookies like following:
@page "/counter"
@rendermode InteractiveAuto
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@inject IJSRuntime js

<script>
    function getCookie(key) {
            const value = `; ${document.cookie}`;
            const parts = value.split(`; ${key}=`);
            if (parts.length === 2) return parts.pop().split(';').shift();
        }

    function setCookie(key, value) {
        document.cookie = `${key}=${value}`;
    }
</script>


@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    private HttpContext? HttpContext { get; set; }
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (HttpContext != null)
        {
            //read
            var value = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["key"];
            //set
            HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("key", "value");
        }
        else
        {
            //read
            var value = await js.InvokeAsync<string>("getCookie", "key");

            //set
            await js.InvokeVoidAsync("setCookie", "key", "value");
        }
    }
}

Refernce : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-8.0#ihttpcontextaccessorhttpcontext-in-razor-components-blazor

OMG it works. Thank you.
